# paypal payment method in 2checkout payment gateway in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, paypal, 2checkout

In checkout page it does not show paypal payment method.
Test mode is unchecked,
Please suggest

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-2checkout-payment/

Answer (score 0):

2checkout would be a separate payment gateway from PayPal.  Have you enabled PayPal separately from 2checkout within your WooCommerce payment gateway settings?

You may be interested in [PayPal for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-for-woocommerce/), which is a free plugin that provides more advanced PayPal integration than the standard version included with WooCommerce.

Comment: payment gateway and payment method are different; 
I wann pay to 2checkout from my paypal account.
Anyways problem solved. thanks for reply